# Sqlite get database values for a date range

Tags: database, sqlite

Couldn't find an answer yet.

I have a db named history where I stored transaction times as:  time with datetime Type.

I have an HTML form where I get the start and end date from the user.

My code is:

```
hist = db.execute("SELECT * FROM history WHERE DATE(time) BETWEEN :start AND :end AND user_id = :i_d ORDER BY time DESC", start=request.form.get("start"), end=request.form.get("end"), i_d=session["user_id"])
```

and I have on the html form side the following:

```
<form action="/history" method="post">
  <h3>Please enter the time range to pull data from</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input autocomplete="off" value="2021-10-14" autofocus class="form-control" name="start" placeholder="start" type="date">
            <input autocomplete="off" value="today" autofocus class="form-control" name="end" placeholder="end" type="date">
            <button onClick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled=true; this.value='Sending…'; " class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

It is not working. I tried adding ' ' to start and end but it didn't help.

When running sqlite3 on my db and excuting

```
SELECT * FROM history WHERE DATE(time) BETWEEN '2021-10-14' AND '2021-10-31' AND user_id = 1 ORDER BY time DESC;
```

It does work. What the issue with my intial code?

Thanks!

Comment: What is this *datetime format*?

Comment: There is no datetime data type in SQLite: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: Thanks, managed to figure out what's the issue, adding str to start=str(request.form.get("start")), end=str(request.form.get("end")) solved it for me. I think because SQLite treat datetime type as Numeric.